# How to list all objects from particular model in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two **models**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()
```

My receipt url looks like this:
[image]

And i would like it to show list of all products, instead of a number of them. How to do this?

**My viewsets:**

```
class ReceiptViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Receipt.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReceiptSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    enter code here
```

**serializers:**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'price']

class ReceiptSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Receipt
        fields = ['id', 'purchase_date', 'shop', 'products']
```

Comment: share your serializers?

Comment: Sorry for that, i updated my question and added serializers there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply specify nested representations using the `depth` option

Give this a try

```
class ReceiptSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ... 

    class Meta:
        model = Receipt
        fields = ['id', 'purchase_date', 'shop', 'products']
        depth = 1
```

Otherwise

```
class ReceiptSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    ... 

    class Meta:
        model = Receipt
        fields = ['id', 'purchase_date', 'shop', 'products']
```

Comment: I tried it and it shows me that: 
TypeError at /receipts/
'Product' object is not iterable

Comment: @santana011 remove the `many=True` and try again, by the way I don't really understand why you named the related connection in plural

Comment: @santana011 how about the first method?

Comment: It works, but i cant figure out why receipt can have only one product. Whenever i try to add another product to receipt it just switches them

Comment: Foreiginkey can have only one relation, in your scenario you can either implement a reverse foreignkey of a manytomany relation.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Sumithran 's solution but i made a small adjustment, rather than using
serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer i used serializers.ModelSerializer and it displayed the products as follows [View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmdqw.png)

Hope it answers what you are looking for :)

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ReciptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Receipt
        fields = ['id', 'purchase_date', 'shop', 'products']
        depth = 1

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: The change should be included in the answer.